# c#: Problem with DllImport on automated testing

Tags: c#, .net

i have a method registered like this:

```
    [DllImport("MyApi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern int SomeRandomCall();
```

and i added the MyApi.dll to the project with "Copy always = true" and locally everything compiles fine and the MSTest Unittests are working...

But: When i try to run the unittests **manually** via console, like:

```
mstest.exe /testcontainer:C:\mytestdll.dll
```

the tests are **failing** and that's because mstest ( which finally executes the tests in my dll ) expects the MyApi.dll to be in its directory ( C:\Windows[...]\IDE 7\MSTest.exe )... Ok, makes sense, but:

**As C# attributes require constant values as parameters, i can not use sth. like "GetCurDir() + "MyApi.dll"... 
What is the best solution to handle this "dynamic path to MyApi.dll" problem?**

The only thing i can think of right now is conditional compiler symbols, but that's pretty dirty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DllImport` is fine as it is; what you need to do is make sure the library loader can find MyApi.dll at runtime.  One way to accomplish this is with the PATH environment variable:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\

mstest.exe /testcontainer:C:\mytestdll.dll
```

...assuming MyApi.dll is in `C:\` (not recommended).

Comment: Even if i think this is somewhat not the ideal solution, i think its reasonable..

Answer (score 0):

Judging from http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/440208-dllimport-attribute-where-default-dll-location, you may want to try preloading the library before calling the [DllImport] decorated method with LoadLibrary.  Hopefully DLL is found if its already loaded, no matter where its loaded from.  You'll need to call LoadLibrary via pinvoke.